# How to invoke Rails cache sweeper from a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I set up a Rails cache sweeper like below:

```
class ArticleSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
  observe Article

  def sweep(article)
    expire_page articles_path
    expire_page author_path(article.author)
    FileUtils.rm_rf "#{page_cache_directory}/articles/page"
  end

  alias_method :after_update, :sweep
  alias_method :after_create, :sweep
end
```

I connected this cache sweeper with the article controller.

The cache sweeping works as a result of controller action of create and update.

However, the main way I update my database records are through a rake task, which uses active record methods of save, update_attributes, etc on the database records.

I thought about adding a model observer class and let this class invoke the sweeper method.
There're alot of comments online about how the cache sweeper should be triggered by model actions instead of controller actions.

But for my application, the rake task may add 100 records when it executes.  So I don't want the cache sweeper to execute 100 times.  As it won't be efficient.

I think it's better to execute it once at the end of the rake task.

So I tried adding this in my rake task:

```
ArticleSweeper.instance.sweep(Article.last)
```

I put a "debugger" statement in there and see that the sweep() method WAS being executed.
However, the cache files are NOT being removed, even though the same code works when it's triggered by controller action.

So my question is: is it possible to trigger the cache sweeper method from a rake task?
And if so, what can I do to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem and stumbled across this: http://www.madebymade.co.uk/blog/2013/08/cache-sweepers-invalidating-caches-from-outside-the-controller/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.